# Make float left inner divs in two columns even if heights could be different with pure css

Tags: css, html, css-float, height

Are there any way to make [this jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hR3Ae/1/) look in two columns like

```
a b
c d
c
c
e f
g h
```

so that the height of the border of `d` is the same as the border of the big block `c` **with pure css**?
The number of blocks is unpredictable.

The blocks should be in two columns.

The blocks that are in one line should have the same height (the height of green borders should be the same).

The content of each block is the text and could be different in its size.

Is it possible to make it with pure css?

I think that souldn't be hard if there were no additional inner divs that I named `<div class="baddiv"></div>` to emphasize the html code structure is a little bit more complicated.
Applying class names and css are allowed for the solution.

Thank you.

And here is [the jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hR3Ae/1/):

```
<style>
.main{
overflow:hidden;
    width:204px;
}
.inner-div{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<div class="main" style=" border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="baddiv">
        <div class="inner-div">a</div>
        <div class="inner-div">b</div>
        <div class="inner-div">ccccccccccc<br/>cccccc<br/>cccccc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-div">d</div>
    <div class="baddiv">
        <div class="inner-div">e</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-div">f</div>
    <div class="inner-div">g</div>
    <div class="inner-div">h</div>
</div>
```

P.S. Also, adding

```
.inner-div{
 min-height:200px;
}
```

is not a perfect solution as a lot of spaces would appear in most of blocks and there is no guarantee one of `div`s would not contain the text that is bigger than 200px in height.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox would be an ideal way to fix this. But if you need browser support, you can force your div's to behave like tables through:

```
display: [table|table-row|table-cell]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pVHw6/

Comment: You added <div>s into the code. It is not allowed in my case as I noted in my question. Thank you.

Comment: Ah okay. I thought i could change the markup structure. Then i would say it's next to impossible to do with your current markup structure, atleast with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
div
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

This can solve your problem. However you need to realign the div's according to layout.